# How to get exact float value in python?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I have a list of floating point numbers. I need to perform to certain addition and multiplication operations on these numbers and the logic of the code requires exact answer(Comparison with other numbers in the same list for example). But it does not give exact answer.The search for a solution to a similar problem suggested the use of decimal class. Still the same problem persisted. Here is an example below:

```
from decimal import Decimal
Decimal(1.2)*Decimal(2)
Decimal('2.399999999999999911182158030')
```

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `Decimal(1.2)` uses the float value for `1.2` while you want the exact value. Use strings instead to use the exact value and get the desired result:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(1.2)
Decimal('1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875')
>>> Decimal("1.2")
Decimal('1.2')
>>> Decimal("1.2")*Decimal("2")
Decimal('2.4')
```

Comment: Libraries similar to Decimal in other languages tend to disallow passing in floats/double to try to avoid this exact problem. This answer is certainly the best approach.

Answer (score -1):

If you like to use the `decimal` module, please set your `preciscion` accordingly.
Example:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from decimal import getcontext

# your code without setting 'prec'
print('Precision :', getcontext().prec)
a = Decimal(1.2) * Decimal(2)
print('result :', a)

# setting 'prec' to 16
getcontext().prec = 16
print('Precision :', getcontext().prec)
a = Decimal(1.2) * Decimal(2)
print('result :', a)
```

output:

```
Precision : 28
result : 2.399999999999999911182158030
Precision : 16
result : 2.400000000000000
```

For more information see the [decimal module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/decimal.html)

Comment: This just hides the precision loss due to using the float value of 1.2. You've just set a precision less than the one from a bare float. If setting less precision is a way to get a better precisioin, there is a problem somewhere.