# How to perform approximate structural pattern matching for floats and complex

Tags: python, floating-point, complex-numbers, approximate, structural-pattern-matching

I've read about and understand [floating point round-off issues](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) such as:

```
>>> sum([0.1] * 10) == 1.0
False

>>> 1.1 + 2.2 == 3.3
False

>>> sin(radians(45)) == sqrt(2) / 2
False
```

I also know how to work around these issues with [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) and [cmath.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#cmath.isclose).

The question is how to apply those work arounds to Python's match/case statement.  I would like this to work:

```
match 1.1 + 2.2:
    case 3.3:
        print('hit!')  # currently, this doesn't match
```

Comment: Be warned that `*.isclose` are heuristics, and can themselves fail in unexpected ways.

Comment: For instance, `math.isclose(a, b)` and `math.isclose(b, c)` but not `math.isclose(a, c)`. (E.g. with default settings, `a,b,c = 1, 1.0000000005, 1.0000000015`)

Comment: The isclose() functions have precise definitions and are completely controllable. They are offered by the standard library as the accepted way to make comparisons for nearby floats.  No one made the claim that isclose() is transitive nor is that relevant to this use case — it is a red herring to create a vague and unactionable sense of worry.  If there is a better solution, please post it.

Comment: I believe this is close to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51018201/how-to-get-exact-float-value-in-python

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The key to the solution is to build a wrapper that overrides the `__eq__` method and replaces it with an approximate match:

```
import cmath

class Approximately(complex):

    def __new__(cls, x, /, **kwargs):
        result = complex.__new__(cls, x)
        result.kwargs = kwargs
        return result

    def __eq__(self, other):
        try:
            return isclose(self, other, **self.kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            return NotImplemented
```

It creates approximate equality tests for both float values and complex values:

```
>>> Approximately(1.1 + 2.2) == 3.3
True
>>> Approximately(1.1 + 2.2, abs_tol=0.2) == 3.4
True
>>> Approximately(1.1j + 2.2j) == 0.0 + 3.3j
True
```

Here is how to use it in a match/case statement:

```
for x in [sum([0.1] * 10), 1.1 + 2.2, sin(radians(45))]:
    match Approximately(x):
        case 1.0:
            print(x, 'sums to about 1.0')
        case 3.3:
            print(x, 'sums to about 3.3')
        case 0.7071067811865475:
            print(x, 'is close to sqrt(2) / 2')
        case _:
            print('Mismatch')
```

This outputs:

```
0.9999999999999999 sums to about 1.0
3.3000000000000003 sums to about 3.3
0.7071067811865475 is close to sqrt(2) / 2
```

Comment: Since timestamps are floats, this should also work well for approximate times.

Comment: Minor note: A type-check of some sort would be needed in `__eq__` to make this work in mixed-type `match`es, e.g. adding `if not isinstance(other, numbers.Complex): return NotImplemented` (`Complex` is a superclass of `Real`, so it would support most numeric types aside from `decimal.Decimal`, which is a weirdo case) so it wouldn't die with a `TypeError` when the input might be non-numeric (because other `case`s are intended to catch non-numeric stuff).

Answer (score 29):

Raymond's answer is very fancy and ergonomic, but seems like a lot of magic for something that could be much simpler.  A more minimal version would just be to capture the calculated value and just explicitly check whether the things are "close", e.g.:

```
import math

match 1.1 + 2.2:
    case x if math.isclose(x, 3.3):
        print(f"{x} is close to 3.3")
    case x:
        print(f"{x} wasn't close)
```

I'd also suggest only using `cmath.isclose()` where/when you actually need it, using appropriate types lets you ensure your code is doing what you expect.

The above example is just the minimum code used to demonstrate the matching and, as pointed out in the comments, could be more easily implemented using a traditional `if` statement.  At the risk of derailing the original question, this is a somewhat more complete example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Square:
    size: float

@dataclass
class Rectangle:
    width: float
    height: float

def classify(obj: Square | Rectangle) -> str:
    match obj:
        case Square(size=x) if math.isclose(x, 1):
            return "~unit square"

        case Square(size=x):
            return f"square, size={x}"

        case Rectangle(width=w, height=h) if math.isclose(w, h):
            return "~square rectangle"

        case Rectangle(width=w, height=h):
            return f"rectangle, width={w}, height={h}"

almost_one = 1 + 1e-10
print(classify(Square(almost_one)))
print(classify(Rectangle(1, almost_one)))
print(classify(Rectangle(1, 2)))
```

Not sure if I'd actually use a `match` statement here, but is hopefully more representative!

Comment: @RaymondHettinger can you explain a bit more? I thought the use of a match/case vs if/elif depends on the semantics you're trying to implement. Why does the matching expression matter in this decision? Is this a Python specific thing or a general idea your talking about?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: When you say "*always* do better with if-elif-else chain", what do you mean? Your solution (which I up-voted) reduces code duplication in exchange for a little more magic-at-a-distance, but performance-wise they should be essentially identical (hypothetical hash-based `match`es can't optimize either; it'll always be equivalent to if-elif-else under the hood). You still get to pass a computed value to the `match` without prestoring it in a variable, you can still theoretically put in `case`s for other types, etc. Am I missing something that makes this fundamentally worse?

Comment: @RaymondHettinger: Would it look better with multiple `case x if math.isclose(x, some_float)` patterns? As it is, it could indeed be completely replaced with `if math.isclose(1.1 + 2.2, 3.3):`.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger sure, it can be substituted with `if-elif`, but why do it?

Comment: @BarryBostwick match/case with only guards is wordier, more nested, less clear, and likely slower than an equivalent if-elif-else-chain.